# ngModel leaves blank screen when called

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-ngmodel

I'm trying to learn the basics of Angular2, so I was trying to make some tests. I've already downloaded `typescript` and `angular/cli`.

I can use iterpolation, property binding, etc. but when I try to use a **two-way data-binding** like that(in `app.component.html` for tests):

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="test.description">
```

and the `ng server` refreshes, all the things that I've done disappear and all I see is a blank screen.

I ask that the answers be simple, because I'm a begginner in using angular.

**EDIT:**
Even after updating `app.modules.ts`, my console keep displaying the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'NgModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
</p>

<input type="text" [ERROR ->][(NgModel)]="test.description" >`
```

Comment: have you declared the object test?

Comment: Yes, even when I call, for example, `{{test.description}}` it displays the value correctly, the problem is when I try to do anything using `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: don't capitalize it. use lowercase - ngModel

Comment: as an aside - many people complain about this with angular :-)  html markup isn't usually case sensitive, but Angular HTML markup is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must be getting an error on console, to use **`ngModel`**, Add this to your Module,

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
imports: [
         FormsModule      
]
```

Use the correct syntax **`ngModel`**

```
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="test.description">
```

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan - i dont think this i necessary to use ngModel. I use it in all of my apps and have never utilized this module.

Comment: Yes - you can use ngModel with either template driven forms or reactive forms. Template driven forms just use the more basic 'FormsModule' . But even so, you don't need to import a special Forms module unless using ngModel inside form tags and you need to reference the input states in the template of the form.

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel  <-- see here.   "This directive can be used by itself or as part of a larger form. All you need is the ngModel selector to activate it."

Comment: After adding the changes to the module, it worked! Even if the input has no `name` it works. Thank you all!

Comment: Ah yes, judging from the documentation - they say you can use it standalone without other form modules, but to do so, you have to specifically import it. -->  import { NgModel } from '@angular/forms';  <--- importing the entire module imports NgModel as well so that works

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a "name" attribute on the input in order to make it work with ngModel

```
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="test.description">
```

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o31Ilus3IKJnLZcUQlMW?p=preview)

Comment: I have always used names with my ngModel inputs as well, but judging from the official documentation - it isn't necessary when using a standalone ngModel input. https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel    see the first 'How to Use' example.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that simply adding formsModule to the imports in the `app.module.ts` folder (or wherever the module file is) fixes this problem. It's simply trying to implement something in a library currently unaccessible. You also need to add an import statement at the top of the file.

```
import { FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';



@NgModule(imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule]})
```

This resolved my own problems with the `ngModule` not working.